# how can i check the presence of sound in a video using a script

Tags: windows, validation, video

Hi
i am working for a broadcasting company, we have a PC with TV tuner Card (windows xp), this PC is recording channel TV 24h/24 no stop.
the output are video files "wmv" each one has a duration of an hour.
The video files are copied automatically to a NAS, then final users works on them.

the problem is sometimes, there is no signal in the antenna, or there is just video without sound, then the video files recorded are no more exploitables.

i am searching for a way to write a script that can check a file after being recorded before being transfered to the NAS, the script must check the presence of the sound (perhaps volume statistics) to be sure the sounds exists really, same thing of video.
(for video i am using a script checking the size of the file)

is there anyway to do so ?
is there any command line in vlc, mplayer, media player classic, ..... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use ffmpeg (http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/229/extract-audio-from-video-or-online-stream/) to dump the audio to a seperate file in a compressed state, and the filesize can give you some information about the amount of data?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just tried what you say, unfortunately the size is the same for a correct file and a no exploitable file. the correct file has a size 149M, sound with ffmpeg has a size of 56M, the corrupt file has a size of 117M, (one image for the whole video and no sound), sound with ffmpeg has a size of 56M exactly the same size as for a correct file, can't use this method to check the presence of the sound.